# Is there a tool for copying files directly from any running Kubernetes pod to another?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, rsync, synchronization, live-migration

I would like to move a large file set from a running Kubernetes pod to another (possibly in another cluster) in order to migrate quickly from one Storage Class to another with little or no downtime.

I want the files to be copied directly from one pod to the other, preferably with rsync.

I have figured out how to accomplish the task, but I am wondering if there is an existing tool before I embark on writing one.

Is there a simple tool for reliably copying files directly from any running Kubernetes pod to another?

NB: 'kubectl cp' cannot accomplish this task as of kubectl v1.25.1

```bash
➜  ~ kubectl run --image nginx nginx1       
pod/nginx1 created
➜  ~ kubectl run --image nginx nginx2
pod/nginx2 created
➜  ~ kubectl cp nginx1:/etc/nginx.conf nginx2:/etc/nginx.conf 
error: one of src or dest must be a local file specification
```

Comment: use `kubectl cp` for example `kubectl cp pod-1:my-file pod-2:my-file`

Comment: @asktyagi - kubectl cp does not accomplish this task as of kubctl v1.25.1. See amendment to question a above for an example.